# call function within api call angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to call function in to api call. up till now I have done the following logic but it is not working.

### code

```
changeStatus(id) {
    this.http.post('https://localhost:44300/api/apis/ChangeStatus/' + id, "")
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this._data = data.json(),
                this.getAllUser();
            },
            err => this.logError(err)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: function is not called

Comment: Could you try replacing the `,` with a `;` after `data.json()`?

Comment: yesssssss dude Its working by replacing `,` to `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple typo - just replace the `,` with a `;` after `data.json()`.